# Unable to recover a deleted minecraft world file

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had a really good minecraft world, but somehow it got deleted, i didn't notice it until recently i wanted to go back to that world for nostalgic reasons. I already tried previous versions, but there's nothing there. I already tried numerous file recovery programs but I can't find it anywhere. I think it's overwritten because it was deleted in a different windows version. But also my C disk is pretty small so i think the location has been overwritten a lot of times, the question is: Is there any way i can still get back that world. Also I still have the crash log files.

Answer (score 0):

If you think your C drive has been overwritten a lot, there's probably no way to get it back I'm afraid. Disk recovery services can be found locally that may be able to help but I wouldn't get your hopes up.

If you're wondering where to find Minecraft saves (in case you hadn't already checked), you can find them in `%appdata%/.minecraft/saves` for the default directory. I'd also implore you to check your recycle bin, just in case